# Show that the vector field $X(x, y, z)=(xy-z^2, yz-x^2, x^2+z^2+xz-1)$ is tangent to the set $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$

Tags: differential-geometry

I know I need to find functions $F(t)$, $G(t)$, and $H(t)$ such that $F(0)=x$, $G(0)=y$, and $H(0)=z$ and $F'(0)=xy-z^2$, $G'(0)=yz-x^2$, and $H'(0)=x^2+z^2+xz-1$.  It's also necessary that $(F(t))^2 +(G(t))^2 + (H(t))^2 = 1$ for all $t$. Just not sure where to go from here...

Comment: To show that $X$ is in the tangent plane, you need only to show that $X$ is perpendicular to the normal of the sphere.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: @user100936 Check the last component of the vector field pls. It does not agree in the body and the heading.

Comment: My apologies.  The heading was correct.  I've updated it.

Comment: @user100936: What is the normal to $x^2 + y^2+z^2=1$?

Comment: Is it $(2x, 2y, -1)$?

Comment: Um... not really. Let $p$ be a point on the sphere, then consider $p$ as a vector, it is normal to the shpere.

Comment: The line through any point on the surface of the sphere say $(x,y,z)$ and origin $(0,0,0)$ is perpendicular to the sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've been taught more from a pure differential geometry perspective, taking about curves on manifolds and such.  I'll try to connect some of the disparate notions here into a coherent whole.

You've been given a set of position vectors ("points") that form a *manifold*.  Let's not worry about what a manifold is.  Let's just say it's a useful word that captures what is typically meant when talking about surfaces, volumes, and such, without necessarily choosing whether the object is 2d or 3d or whatever else.

At some position vector $p$, we can draw a curve $c(t)$ through the point, so that $c(0) = p$.  If the curve is smooth enough and differentiable, we can take a derivative $c'(0)$.  This is a vector, and a different kind of vector from a position vector.  This is usually called a *tangent vector*.

The set of all possible tangent vectors at a point $p$ forms what's called the *tangent space* at $p$.

Your definition of what it means for a vector field to be tangent is then equivalent to the following:

> A vector field $X$ is tangent to a manifold $A$ if at every point $p$, $X(p)$ lies entirely in the tangent space at $p$.

You should be able to see that this definition is equivalent to yours.  If $X(p)$ does indeed lie in the tangent space, than you can draw some curve whose derivative is the tangent vector $X(p)$.  We're not at all concerned with the behavior of the curve away from $p$, so finding these functions is overkill.

For your 2d manifold, the tangent space at any point $p$ is the plane tangent to the sphere at that point.  To say that $X(p)$ lies entirely in the tangent space is to say that $X(p)$ has *no component* perpendicular to the tangent plane, or rather, that it has no component along the normal to the tangent plane.  The normal vector could also be said to be $p$, which is exactly what MLT reasoned.  MLT showed that the projection of $X(p)$ along the normal direction $p$ is zero, therefore $X(p)$ has no normal component and must lie entirely in the tangent plane at each point $p$.

Comment: That helps connect the dots, but I'm not quite there yet.  Just to clarify: $c(t)$ must be drawn on the manifold?  I'm still not seeing why $X(p)$ having no normal component implies the existence of a curve satisfying the properties given in the definition.

Comment: Yes, $c(t)$ is drawn on the manifold. Proving the existence of such a curve can be done indirectly.  A tangent vector is the derivative of some curve through $p$.  If $X(p)$ has no normal component, then it is coincident with some tangent vector $v$ at $p$.  There *must* exist at least one such curve with derivative $v$ at $p$, or else $v$ is not a tangent vector.

Comment: _" If X(p) has no normal component, then it is coincident with some tangent vector v at p."_ Why is this true?

Comment: Let me clarify.  "If $X(p)$ has no normal component, then it lies in the tangent plane."  (Why? Because the union of the tangent plane and its orthogonal complement is $\mathbb R^3$.  A vector with zero component along the normal direction must have all its remaining components in the tangent plane.)  Then, we say that elements of the tangent plane are tangent vectors.  Since $X(p)$ lies in the tangent plane, it is a tangent vector.

Comment: I get that part.  How do we know that every element of the tangent plane is a tangent vector?

Comment: That's the definition of the tangent space (which, in this case, is a plane): the collection of all tangent vectors at a point.

Comment: How do we know that the tangent space is in fact a plane?  That does not seem obvious from the definition.

Comment: You should be able to imagine the sphere that is being described and see that the set of vectors tangent to the sphere at any point form a planar vector space.  In the general case, the tangent space has the same dimension as the manifold, but proving this is more involved and way beyond the scope of this problem.  Without giving you *even more* of an introduction into the geometry of manifolds, there are reasons you've been taught in terms of curves, but they're clumsy to actually use, and several curves would fit the requirements (no uniqueness). I suspect you're not supposed to use curves.

Comment: I see.  It's difficult to directly prove, but I see how it is true (it might be easier using spherical coordinates and rotating a smooth curve along the unit sphere).  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

We will show that the vector field is perpendicular to any point $(x,y,z)$ on sphere by considering the dot product of the vector field and the normal to the sphere at that point.
$(xy-z^2,yz-x^2,x^2+z^2+xz-1)\cdot(x,y,z)=x^2y-xz^2+zy^2-yx^2+zx^2+z^3+xz^2-z=zy^2+zx^2+z^3-z=z(x^2+y^2+z^2-1).$ We know on the surface of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$. Therefore the result holds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the definition of tangency I was given in class does not involve dot products or normal vectors.  Rather, it states that a vector field $X(x, t)$ is tangent to a set $A$ if for every point $x$ in $A$, there exists a curve in $A$, $c(t)$, satisfying $c'(0)=X(x, 0)$ and $c(0)=x$.  It is not obvious that the two definitions are equivalent.